# Compare Two Columns with attached columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet with 4 columns. The first two columns are UPC and QOH from day 1, the second two columns are UPC and QOH from day 2.

I need to sort and compare both sets by UPC and highlight any differences.  If a UPC is missing out of either set I need to add a space in the other set for it.

I need to highlight (or somehow note) missing UPCs and highlight differences in QOH.  I'm not sure how to go about that leaving the relationship between set one intact (and set two).

Hopefully the example graphic I've attached makes it clearer.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You will need to do this with VBA. If you don't need the second column's values to be moved, then conditional formatting would be enough. What have you tried and what is your question?

Comment: I need the second columns value to stay "bound" to the first column.  I thought I might have to use VBA.  The UPC's are already sorted in ascending order so I am thinking I have to do some kind of comparison and if they aren't equal, push both the lesser UPC and its associated quantity down...then after I have done that come back and compare QTY.  But I'm not sure if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: If the data input/output format can be changed, then this can also be done with a pivot table (with conditional formatting) or power query (again with conditional formatting). In the end the solution you pick really depends on what you define as "better"

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve? You note a comparison of two days but will this ultimately extend to adding comparisons including days 3, 4, ...? There are two sorts of error you are concerned with: inconsistency in the list of UPC's between days and where a UPC does occur on both days, inconsistency between the associated QTY values. But what will you do when you find such inconsistencies? Is it about data cleaning or something else? There are a myriad of ways of detecting the inconsistencies but the method chosen should perhaps reflect the unstated end goal.